# get text from regional setting of jquery date picker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-datepicker

i am using jquery date picker for my client .. now for globalisation i have to localise the date picker control also . that is demonstrated on jquery site 
but i want as per our requirement i want to set come other values basis on the selected date & also i want to set innerHtml on a div with text "Today" if user selectes the current date i dont want to make it complex so
 i need to get value of "Today" from 'currentText' value from the date picker regional settings in onSelect : function(dateText, inst){......}


is there any way to get regional settings from "inst" parameter of onSelect function

 or any other method in whci i get the localised text for "Today" in call back method for the instance of the date picker that causes the call back

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can get any option value from a jQueryUI widget using following syntax:

```
$(selector).datepicker('option', 'optionMane');
```

`this` within any of the event callbacks will be the main element the widget is bound to.

In your case you would use:

```
onSelect: function( dateText, inst){
  alert( $(this).datepicker('option','currentText') );
}
```